# Return non-adjacent columns of data with different drop-down criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have a drop down list that I would like to return information from the sheet "Plants". If I choose "fruits" on the dropdown list, I would like to show columns A, C, J, and K if Col E="fruits". If I choose "vegetables" I would like to show columns A, C, M, and N if Col O=TRUE. I tried a few filters that worked individually but wasn't able to figure out how to nest it with an IF function so it would change for all the different drop-down selections, and I'm sure there's a better way of doing it. What is the best way to return non-adjacent columns of data with different drop-down criteria?

Filter examples:

For fruits drop down, I want to return this: =FILTER({Plants!A2:A,Plants!C2:C,Plants!J2:J,Plants!K2:K},Plants!E2:E="Fruits")

For vegetables drop down, I want to use this:
=FILTER({Plants!A:A,Plants!C:C,Plants!M:M,Plants!N:N},Plants!O:O=TRUE)

Comment: May be using name manager and `INDIRECT()` would be best approach.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output